# Adding a new column to a text file in python

Tags: python, parsing

I am very new to python. I am trying to parse a lst file and filter the required data and create a text file. The next think I am trying to do is to add a column in the text file indicating the function type or variable. I am unable to attain the exact output. I did parse the file filter it and the last step is to add the extra column which has "i" assigned to functions with arguments, "v" for void functions and "a" for variables like the input file would contain

```
0001016a g     F .text  00000016 data_init(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)
2007c234 g     O .bss   00000004 servo_turner_claw2
2007c140 g     O .data  00000004 _impure_ptr
2007c000 g       .data  00000000 _data
2007c5bc g       .bss   00000000 _pvHeapStart
00010c4c g     F .text  00000018 open_claw2()
2007c1bc g       .data  00000000 _edata
00010278 g     F .text  00000004 operator new(unsigned int)
2007c0dc g     O .data  00000004 __ctype_ptr__
2007c5ac g     O .bss   00000004 __malloc_sbrk_start
2007c5b0 g     O .bss   00000004 __malloc_free_list
00010c9c g     F .text  00000024 rotate_claw2_anticlkwise()
```

the output expected is

```
a  2007c140  .data  _impure_ptr
a  2007c000  .data  _data
a  2007c5bc  .bss  _pvHeapStart
v  00010c4c  .text  open_claw2()
a  2007c1bc  .data  _edata
i  00010278  .text  operator  new(unsigned  i  00010278  .text  operator  new(unsigned  i  00010278  .text  operator  new(unsigned  i  00010278  .text  operator  new(unsigned  a  2007c0dc  .data  __ctype_ptr__
a  2007c5ac  .bss  __malloc_sbrk_start
a  2007c5b0  .bss  __malloc_free_list
v  00010c9c  .text  rotate_claw2_anticlkwise()
```

The code lodic I wrote is

```
f = open("final_lst.txt", "r+")
g = open("Filtered_lut.txt", "w+")

filter_list = ["int","unsigned"]
for line in f:
    if ".data" in line :
        columns = line.split("  ")
        columns.insert(0, "va")
        g.write("  ".join(columns)+"\t")

    if ".text" in line:
        if "(" in line:
            for word in filter_list:
                columns = line.split("  ")
                columns.insert(0, "vi")
                g.write("  ".join(columns)+"\t")

        if "()" in line:
            columns = line.split("  ")
            columns.insert(0, "vv")
            g.write("\t".join(columns)+"\t")


f.close()
g.close()
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include what is currently not working in your code. Include any error messages (if any) and provide sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: I'm not sure from your question exactly what you expect the output to be, but, a couple of things jump out. First, if you want each entry on a separate line you have to write newline characters (e.g. `g.write("  ".join(columns)+"\t\n")`. Also, I think you need to look at the conditional logic on the ".text" part. Perhaps you need the `if "()" in line:` block first, then the `if "(" in line` as an `elif` (at the moment, for lines with "()" both blocks will be executed.

Comment: @NickEdwards Thanks for the suggestion of having the "()" check first. It did help me. but I am still unable to get the desired output

Comment: I was able to add "i" but then it doesn't write the complete function name to the output file. it only take first argument like                                                 v  000171ec  .text  sys_clock_pll0_feed()                                                        
  i  00017200  .text  sys_clock_configure_pll(unsigned int,                                       
  i  00017200  .text  sys_clock_configure_pll(unsigned int,                              
  i  00017200  .text  sys_clock_configure_pll(unsigned int,